# vim syntax: how to use contained fields

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953042/vim-syntax-match-only-when-between-other-matches)

The syntax of my logs has changed.  I now have to include a username before the time, so the new format is:

```
[username] time LEVEL filepath:line - message
```

I have no problem defining the various regions:

```
syn region logUser start=+^\[+ end=+\] +me=e-1 contained
syn match logTime "\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2},\d\{3}" contained
syn keyword logCritical CRITICAL contained
syn keyword logError ERROR contained
syn keyword logWarn WARN contained
syn keyword logInfo INFO contained
syn keyword logDebug DEBUG contained
syn match logFileAndNumber " \S\+:\d\+ - " contains=logFile,logLineNumber
syn match logFile " \S\+:" contained
syn match logLineNumber "\d\+" contained
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to create a region at the beginning, so that I don't get highlighting any time I see one of the log levels, or if a timestamp appears in the message or something.  The answer to the linked question works for the previous format, but doesn't have much in the way of explanation so I don't really understand what it's doing.

EDIT: Is there no way to simply define the smaller regions and then define the larger region as a sequence of the smaller ones?  I know this wouldn't work, but something along the lines of:

```
syn match logBeginning "$logUser $logTime [$logCritical|$logError|$logWarn|$logInfo|$logDebug]"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sequence (user, time, severity, ...) is fixed, you can use `nextgroup=...` attribute to chain them together. So, make the first (`logUser`) an uncontained one (so that it matches anywhere), and instruct Vim to check for `logTime` after it (only followed by whitespace). All other groups are `contained` to avoid matches elsewhere.

```
syn region logUser start=+^\[+ end=+\] +me=e-1 nextgroup=logTime skipwhite
syn match logTime "\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2},\d\{3}" contained nextgroup=logCritical,logError,logWarn,logInfo,logDebug skipwhite
...
```

Cp. `:help :syn-nextgroup`.